# Google App Engine: deploying the same code to multiple applications

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment

I have a Google App Engine application called "myapp" whose code is in a directory called "myapp". Its "app.yaml" file says:

```
application: myapp
```

I want to create a completely separate application called "myapp-2" with identical code to the original one. I have created another configuration file called "app2.yaml" in the same "myapp" directory that says:

```
application: myapp-2
```

If I run

```
google_appengine/appcfg.py --config_file "app2.yaml" update myapp/
```

will the code be uploaded to the application "myapp-2", with no effect whatsoever on the original "myapp"?

If not, is there another way to create a Google App Engine application with identical code to an existing one?

Answer (score 1):

If all configs in the yaml are same (builtins, handlers, etc), you can just call appcfg with --application parameter, which will override the application defined in the app.yaml file

Reference: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Command-line_arguments